# Confused by Linq and grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I'm playing around with Entity Framework and Linq and trying to learn me some new things. Now I have a problem that I would easily solve with SQL but want to solve it with Linq instead.

I have one Color class, and one Car class. Each Car object has an color.

```
public class Color
{
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public Guid CarID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public int ColorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Color CarColor { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a query to get all colors (ID and name) and the number of cars using that color (if any).

This attempt gives me almost the right result, but it excludes Colors that are not used.

```
        var n3 = from car in db.Cars
                 join c in db.Colors on car.ColorID equals c.ColorID into j1
                 from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 group j2 by j2.ColorID into colorgroup
                 select new ColorCarCount
                 {
                     CarCount = colorgroup.Count(t => t.ColorID != null),
                     ColorID = colorgroup.Key, //colorgroup.Key,
                     Name = colorgroup.FirstOrDefault().Name
                 };
```

This attempt feels best, but here I can't get the color name:

```
        var n4 = from c in db.Colors
                 join car in db.Cars on c.ColorID equals car.ColorID into j1
                 from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 group j2 by j2.ColorID into colorgroup
                 select new ColorCarCount
                 {
                     CarCount = colorgroup.Count(t => t.ColorID != null),
                     ColorID = colorgroup.Key, 
                     Name = "Can't get color name here"
                 };
```

Any suggestions? Yes, I have read similar question but I don't really get it - but I'm sure it's easy :-)

Comment: Never tried `FirstOrDefault().Name`, always used `colorgroup.Max(x=> x.name)`

Comment: Interesting, that gives me the same result. I wonder if there is any good practice for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var n4 = from c in db.Colors
             join car in db.Cars on c.ColorID equals car.ColorID into tmp
             from car in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             group car by c into colorgroup
             select new ColorCarCount
             {
                 CarCount = colorgroup.Count(),
                 ColorID = colorgroup.Key.ColorID,
                 Name = colorgroup.Key.Name
             };
```

Comment: Nice try (and fast :-)), but on the last two lines "c" can't be used. I tried colorgroup.FirstOrDefault() but then name of the color can't be accessed.

Comment: @PEK, fixed! `colorgroup.Key` is the key of the grouping, so in this case it's the color.

Comment: You almost nailed it :-) Change CarCount = colorgroup.Count(t => t.ColorID != null) then everything works fine. Thanks for quick support - you is my favorite teacher for the day ;-).